# CATransform3DMakeRotation and shadow

Tags: ios, calayer, catransform3d

I'm creating the flip animation library.

In two words, I create the CALayer and rotate it using CoreAnimation's CATransform3DMakeRotation.

The question is – is there a way to add a shadow to that scene? Without rewriting the whole code with OpenGL :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`CAGradientLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html). I am currently using it to add shadows in a similar situation. May be costly performance-wise (still have to check that), but looks quite convincing.

Add `CAGradientLayer` as sublayer(s) to your layers and animate its `opacity`. You may have to play around a little with the gradient stops and colors to get them right.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `OpenGL` but have you checked `CATransform3D`

Add

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(d) (d * M_PI / 180)
```

in .pch file

```
CATransform3D myTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
myTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
myTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
myView.layer.transform = myTransform;
```

you can go on changing the angle here `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90)`

Here you can add shadow to `myView`.